# Dose the display port daisy chain feature work if the last monitor in chain is an HDMI monitor ?

Tags: hdmi, displayport

Dose the display port daisy chain feature work if the last monitor in the chain is not a display port monitor, but rather an HDMI monitor.

So the setup would go like this :

`Laptop -> (display link cable) -> display link monitor 1080p -> (display link to hdmi cable) -> hdmi monitor 1080p.`

Would that work ?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried that particular setup myself, but I did have good results with the 2nd monitor being DVI in stead of HDMI, which amounts to the same thing.

Yes, it is supposed to work, provided the laptop can drive 2 monitors across the link.
In other words: If it works with 2 DP monitors it should work if the 2nd monitor is HDMI or DVI too.
Please note: Many laptops are not capable of doing that. Not all regular GFX cards in desktop computers either for that matter.